# Creating custom dictionaries in aspell with the C API

Tags: c++, c, aspell

I am using aspell in my application for spell checking (a c/c++ app), and I want to use it to find best alternatives in a custom work list.  I don't want to use a standard dictionary, as I only want to find words in my word list.  I can find ways of adding words to a dictionary (aspell_speller_add_to_personal and aspell_speller_add_to_session), but I don't know how to start with an empty dictionary that I can then populate at run time.

Has anybody done this, or know how to do it?  Alternatively, any recommendations for algorithms for choosing a "best match" in a word list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this about three years ago. It was in a convoluted way that included creating a  dictionary data structure from an existing file, deleting it and adding words using 
aspeller::Dictionary::add(). It was tough.

If you do not have to use aspell, you may try [hunspell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunspell), which may or may not be easier to customize.

See also [Peter Norvig's Great Paper](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) about writing a spelling corrector.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought I might have to mess with dictionary files.  The paper you pointed me to is great and I think I shall work with it.